# How to set multiple file entry and output in project with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

How to set multiple file entry/output in project with webpack?

I follow http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/ success compile if only one file in one entry/output...

directory

```
app
webpack.config.js
./assets
././javascripts/Administrator/Article/Create/Base.js
././javascripts/Administrator/Article/Edit/Base.js
././javascripts/Account/Index/Base.js
././javascripts/Contact/Index/Base.js
...
```

how to output like this?

```
././javascripts/Administrator/Article/Create/bundle.js
././javascripts/Administrator/Article/Edit/bundle.js
././javascripts/Account/Index/bundle.js
././javascripts/Contact/Index/bundle.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'AdministratorArticleCreate':['./assets/javascripts/Administrator/Article/Create/Base.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: 
  }

    // if only one file
    // entry: "./assets/javascripts/Administrator/Article/Create/Base.js",
    // output: {
    //     // path: __dirname,
    //     path: "./assets/javascripts/Administrator/Article/Create/",
    //     filename: "bundle.js"
    // }
};
```

Comment: I also met this problem and cannot find any solution. Would be great if someone could share a solution

Answer (score 94):

For many entry points use arrays as a value of `entry` property:

```
entry: {
  app: ['./app/main.js', '.lib/index.js'],
  vendors: ['react']
}
```

`app` and `vendors` are arrays, so you can put there as many file paths as you need.

For output case:

```
output: {
  path: staticPath,
  filename: '[name].js'
}
```

The `[name]` is taken from `entry` properties, so if we have `app` and `vendors` as properties, we got 2 output files - `app.js` and `vendors.js`.

[Documentation link](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputfilename)

Comment: What you want to have different file extensions, e.g., output `app.js` and `styles.css`?

Comment: Is it possible to have different output folder?

Comment: How can I do something like `entry: ./app/js/*.js`? Put file name one by one is too painful.

Comment: what that mean for at compile time . 'main.js'  can ask for module from index.js ?

Comment: doesn't work!  entry: {
    app: settings.themeLocation + "js/vote-scripts.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "[name].js"}

Answer (score 87):

If you want to output to multiple directories, you can use the path as the entry name. For example if you want this directory structure:

```
apps
├── dir1
│   └── js
│       ├── main.js [entry 1]
│       └── bundle.js [output 1]
└── dir2
    ├── index.js [entry 2]
    └── foo.js [output 2]
```

Then try this in your module.exports:

```
{
  entry: {
    'dir1/js/bundle': path.resolve(__dirname, '/apps/dir1/js/main.js'),
    'dir2/foo' : path.resolve(__dirname, '/apps/dir2/index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/apps'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: brilliant -- put the path elements into the "name" of the entry point...

Comment: Thank you for actually providing a visual diagram of how it works.

Comment: useful except for the duplicate directory names

Comment: Slightly hackish and (probably) unofficial, but a good one. A really good one.

Answer (score 40):

what really solved it for me was this:

```
entry:  {
    app : __dirname + "/app/views/app/app.js",
    admin : __dirname + "/app/views/admin/admin.js"
}

output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "[name].js"
},
```

Comment: The only thing I would note is that this uses the key to replace "[name]" so you can't have invalid characters in the key (e.g. _local-admin_ would not be valid), but this is rather minor.

Answer (score 12):

You can detect multiple entries and generate separate output files by using [glob sync](http://adilapapaya.com/docs/glob/readme_3.2.7.html) patterns.

Put this into your `webpack.config.js` (without the `...`)

```
const glob = require("glob");
...
module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  ...
  entry: glob.sync("./javascripts/**/*.js").reduce((acc, item) => {
    const path = item.split("/");
    path.pop();
    const name = path.join('/');
    acc[name] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
  output: {
    filename: "[name]/bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "")
  },
  ...
});
```

This "should" give you the desired output.

Answer (score 9):

What if you want to get output files as `foo.css` and `bar.js` at the same time? the answers above seem incapable to handle this.

The sane way is to use [multi-compiler](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/multi-compiler/webpack.config.js). One input file one config object one output file. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38132106/2803340).

Answer (score 5):

this webpack plugin [web-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gwuhaolin/web-webpack-plugin) can resolve it in a sample way.

`AutoWebPlugin` can find all page entry in an directory,then auto config an `WebPlugin` for every page to output an html file,you can use it as below:

**webpack config**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new AutoWebPlugin(
            // the directory hold all pages
            './src/', 
            {
            // the template file path used by all pages
            template: './src/template.html',
            // javascript main file for current page,if it is null will use index.js in current page directory as main file
            entity: null,
            // extract common chunk for all pages and then put it into a file named common,if it is null then not do extract action
            // achieve by CommonsChunkPlugin
            commonsChunk: 'common',
            // pre append to all page's entry
            preEntrys:['./path/to/file1.js'],
            // post append to all page's entry
            postEntrys:['./path/to/file2.js'],
        }),
    ]
};
```

**src directory**

```
── src
│   ├── home
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── ie_polyfill.js
│   ├── login
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── polyfill.js
│   ├── signup
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── template.html
```

**output directory**

```
├── dist
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── home.html
│   ├── home.js
│   ├── ie_polyfill.js
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── login.js
│   ├── polyfill.js
│   ├── signup.html
│   └── signup.js
```

`AutoWebPlugin` find all page `home login signup` directory in `./src/`,for this three page `home login signup` will use `index.js` as main file and output three html file home.html login.html signup.html`

see [doc:auto detect html entry](https://github.com/gwuhaolin/web-webpack-plugin#auto-detect-html-entry-demo)

Answer (score 2):

This question is 2 years old so I think the author has almost certainly moved on from this issue, but to anyone landing here more recently I had a really similar need and was able to write my own plugin to allow for dynamic output paths/names from known and/or unknown entry points.

[My problem and thought process for the solution can be found here](https://hackernoon.com/webpack-creating-dynamically-named-outputs-for-wildcarded-entry-files-9241f596b065).

[And the Node package itself here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-entry-plus).

Answer (score 1):

For my use case I actually needed to use different templates based on environment. To achieve this I passed in the NODE_ENV variable

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const ENVIRONMENT = env.NODE_ENV;
  let INDEX_HTML = 'index.html';
  if (ENVIRONMENT === 'staging') {
    INDEX_HTML = 'index-stg.html';
  }
```

Then:

```
if (NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
   INDEX_HTML = 'index-stg.html';
}
```

In the output:

```
output: {
      path: process.cwd() + '/build',
      filename: `[name].js`,
      chunkFilename: `[${HASH_MODE}].[name].js`
    },
```

plugins:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: `app/${INDEX_HTML}`,
      }),
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following, I was able to get webpack to search for typescript and sass files.

```
...
entry: glob
  .sync("./src/{sass,js}/**/*.{ts,scss}")
  .reduce(function (obj, el) {
    obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
    return obj;
  }, {}),
...
```