# Dynamic import in Webpack: it is possible to distribute chunks between subfolders?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Note: this question about **chunks**, not output bundles.

If we need to distribute `webpack` output bundles between multiple subpaths, we can do it next way (unusual, but I use absolute paths):

```
const WEBPACK_CONFIG = {

    // ...
    entry: {
        'open/js/testOpenEntryPoint': 'C:/.../example.loc/source/open/3_es6/testOpenEntryPoint',
        'admin/js/testAdminEntryPoint': 'C:/.../example.loc/source/admin/3_es6/testAdminEntryPoint'
    },

    output: {
      path: 'dest',
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```

However, it does not work for chunks: `chunkFilename`, unlike `filename`, ignores subpath and outputs chunks in single directory. Nevertheless, can we distribute chunks between multiple subpaths as shown below?
Currently I know only multi-compilation solution, but maybe it is more simple way.

source

open

testOpenEntryPoint.js

dyn_load

dynForTestOpenEntryPoint.js

admin

testOpenEntryPoint.js

dyn_load

dynForTestAdminEntryPoint.js

dist

open

testOpenEntryPoint.js

dyn_load

0.js

admin

testOpenEntryPoint.js

dyn_load

1.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multiple output paths in Webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903246/how-to-create-multiple-output-paths-in-webpack-config)

Comment: @Mike Cheel, Afraid not: chunks requires another approach.