# How to configure Babel to properly work with multiple folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I have been using Babel for a while now and it properly converts my ES Next code to the `dist` folder with this command:

```
babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps --copy-files
```

So far I had all my Javascript code in `src`, but now I want to move my React views to the `views` folder next to `src`. I modified the Babel CLI call to this:

```
babel src views --out-dir dist --source-maps --copy-files
```

Now my problem is that while the files are compiled properly none of the `import`s are. For example in my file `Navigation.js` I have this `import`:

```
import Permissions from "../src/utils/permissions";
```

and this will get converted into

```
var _permissions = _interopRequireDefault(require("../src/utils/permissions"));
```

after Babel runs.

How do I configure Babel to fix the imports when I'm working with multiple source directories?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure babel can accomplish this on its own. Its a great tool for transpiling, but think of it as a relentlessly faithful translator.  It will transpile your code, but will not reinterperet your import statements based on your desired output locations and relationships, as far as I know.  So you have 2 options:

1. If using babel only, maintain the relationships between files in your source code and desired output.  For example, if you want all files in `/src` and `src/views` to end up on the same level in `dist`, then you might want to have a folder structure like this:

```
/src
  - /src
  - /views
```

The naming here is a little redundant, I know.  But with `babel src/src src/views --out-dir dist --source-maps --copy-files`, all your files will be transpiled to the same level in `/dist`, and the import relationships will all stay correct.

2. Use a build tool.  Webpack is an even more robust tool, which itself often employs babel.  Webpack is smart enough to re-write your import statements in the bundled code based on how you configure it.  The question [How to create multiple output paths in Webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903246/how-to-create-multiple-output-paths-in-webpack-config) is well answered.  Webpack is a world unto itself, but is powerful enough to accomplish what you want, if you know how to use it.

I'm hoping someone will come along and tell me I'm wrong and that there is some `perfect-for-this-scenario-rewrite-imports-babel-plugin` that does the job.  Here's hoping.  Otherwise I think you have to restructure, or dive into webpack.

Comment: Wait, isn't webpack for web only?

Comment: I believe so.  You didn't specify that your project wasn't a web project, so I made the assumption that it was - my bad.  What kind of project is it?  If its not a web project, then yeah, I guess webpack won't be an option.  There are other build tools like rollup, gulp, grunt, etc., though I'm not as familiar with them, but one of them might be able to handle your task.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified my question.

Comment: This is a regular sever-side node project.

Comment: After doing some research it looks like webpack can indeed be used to build a node project.  I've personally never done it, but it seems possible.  I guess the main point of that answer was to say "you can't" to your original question.  You'll need a build tool.  Again, I hope I'm wrong, but I've never seen babel alone used to do what you're trying to do.