# How to Configure WordPress with Webpack to have Seperate Build Folders for Css and JS

Tags: wordpress, webpack, workflow

I am using Webpack from [@wordpress/scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/) in my WordPress Child theme. By default, the output files are generated inside the `build` folder. However, I would like to change the output path. I would like to separate my compiled js and CSS files into different subfolders inside the build folder, e.g. `build/css` and `build/js`. How can I do this? This is the Webpack configuration I am using:

`webpack.config.js`

```
/**
 * External Dependencies
 */
const path = require( 'path' );
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require( 'webpack-fix-style-only-entries' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js' );

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    ...{
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/scss', 'main.scss' ),
            app: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/js', 'app.js' ),
        },
    },
    plugins: [ new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin() ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Set multiple outputs in Webpack

There are two ways you can achieve this:

**1. Using multi-compiler**
This example is from webpack repository from github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/examples/multi-compiler/webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("../../");

module.exports = [
    {
        name: "mobile",
        // mode: "development || "production",
        entry: "./example",
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "mobile.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                ENV: JSON.stringify("mobile")
            })
        ]
    },

    {
        name: "desktop",
        // mode: "development || "production",
        entry: "./example",
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
            filename: "desktop.js"
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                ENV: JSON.stringify("desktop")
            })
        ]
    }
];
```

**2. Using entry-descriptor**

This the one is use and have tested. Below check out how your webconfig.js should be configured:

```
/**
 * External Dependencies
 */
const path = require( 'path' );
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require( 'webpack-fix-style-only-entries' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js' );


module.exports = {
  ...defaultConfig,
  ...{
    entry: {
      'css/main': path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/scss', 'main.scss' ),
      'js/app': path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/js', 'app.js' ),
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
  }
  plugins: [
    ...defaultConfig.plugins,
    new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin() 
  ],
}
```

NB 1: When you use `path: resolve( process.cwd(), 'build' )` in the output, the `build` folder becomes your root folder.

NB 2: Also notice the way i have extended the plugins for your additional plugins.

Kindly follow this thread for more explanations: [How to create multiple output paths in Webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903246/how-to-create-multiple-output-paths-in-webpack-config)