# How to have Webpack config file entry as './src/*.js'?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to webpack and would like to have my *entry* a little different so that it can take all js file in a directory and create a bundle of all in one.

**My Config File:**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry:  './src/*.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

This result in error as following:
[image]

Here,
**src** is a directory with multiple js files. Any Suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use globs

```
const glob = require("glob");
module.exports = {
  entry: {
     js: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js"),  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a butter.

Answer (score 0):

In case the order does not matter, use @Pandelis' answer. Otherwise, keep reading:

Usually bundle is created from files that `require` or `import` each other. Think about it: if webpack bundles all files in one directory, how does it know which should come first?

What you can do, without altering your files, is to make a new JS file that imports all the files you need:

# `webpack_bundle_me.js`

```
import * as File1 from "./file1.js";
import * as File2 from "./file2.js";
// and so on
```

This way it's easy for you or anyone else to alter the order, without digging in `webpack.config.js`.

You can do this in webpack config as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039902/607407

Comment: Very Good suggestion brother. But It seems @Pandelis' answer worked like a charm.

Comment: Yep, I was just demonstrating alternative approach, for general things, his answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

New Config File:

```
var path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob");
module.exports = {
 entry: {
     js: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js"),  
  }, 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

OR

```
var path = require('path');
const glob = require("glob");
module.exports = {
 entry: glob.sync('./src/*.js'), 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```