# Setting up webpack to export to set folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm working on an old project still running jquery for frontend, java spring for the backend, and maven for building. I've been asked by my boss to introduce react into the stack so we can toy around with converting some of the pages.

My goal is to not impact the existing implementation to heavily and instead output the result of webpack into a defined directory. This way I can just point the backend at that location for pathing.

So far I have an apps folder in my workspace that contains all my react stuff that works on its own. This was generated using 'npx create-react-app folderName'.

I've somewhat read up on how to set the export but am generally confused. As a lot of resources I've found assume a new setup or a replacement of an existing setup. While I'm looking to only replace a single page currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `create-react-app` is the right tool here, since you don't create a complete application with React but incrementally add React code. I would suggest using Webpack on its own. This makes your application cleaner and easier to maintain with your other code.

If you want to keep your React code separate from your existing code you can create a library based on webpack's [Authoring Libraries Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/). You can than render your components with `ReactDOM.render()` ([Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render)). Note that you can call this function (almost) unlimited times on one page which allows you to partially replace your existing code.

Replacing a page then means to create a root DOM element and call the `render` function:

```html
<!-- page.html -->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- more html -->
        <div id="page-root" />
        <!-- more html -->
    </body>
</html>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Page from './routes/YourPageComponent'

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('page-root'));
```

The previous code means that you render your code in the new code which is transpiled by your webpack loaders (e.g. Babel-Loader, Typescript-Loader). If you want to render the code in the existing code, look at the [Doc's about Webpack Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) to export render functions into a global context. The following scripts are an example out of my head.

```
// components/PageExampleComponent.jsx
import React from 'react';

export default function({pageTitle="example"}){
    return <div>
        <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
    </div>
}



// libary/index.js
import PageExampleComponent from './components/PageExampleComponent';

export const MyLibrary = {
    PageExampleComponent
}
```

The previous code requires the following (partial) Webpack config to export `MyLibrary`:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'MyLibrary',
    // based on a fast look into the docs, I think the following are optional:
    libraryTarget: 'window',
    libraryExport: 'default'
  }
};
```

To render a component of this library, you need React and ReactDOM as scripts in your website - and of course your own library script. You can than call `ReactDOM.render()` in plain JavaScript:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(window.MyLibrary.PageExampleComponent),
    document.getElementById('page-root')
```

Another idea would be to move everything into Webpack. This might be easier, as you don't have barriers of different Javascript-Versions and dialects (e.g. with and without JSX support). You can even separate your jQuery code and your React code by using two entry points:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    oldCode: './src/jqueryIndex.js',
    replacement: './src/reactIndex.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
};
```

Comment: This might be the first promising solution i've seen after toying with this for 2 weeks. However, just to be clear what I would do is build up my components in my separate area then build it using webpack as a lib. Then using that lib I would render my component(s) into the target page. Only step I'm missing is how do I get the lib into target for use. As this really was the main question.

Comment: That last bit you edited in after was what I needed. Combined with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39842495/2454297 finally made it click I could place the webpack config at the base folder and tell it what file to take and how to export it to my target folder.