# Can webpack make more than 1 bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, es6-modules

**ES6 Modules:**

My understanding of ES6 modules is that it loads the 'leaf dependencies' (modules that don't import) first in order of their appearance in `.html`. Then, it loads the rest of the files in such a way that a file is only loaded once the file it imports from is loaded. (I understand the rules that determine exactly how these files are loaded is too complicated to bother learning).

**Webpack:**

So far, I've understood that Webpack creates 1 'super' file from 1 `js` script (let's call this script 'jsA') and all the other `js` scripts jsA imports (via CommonJS).

**Question:**

Webpack relies on the idea that every `js` file can be traced back to being imported by `jsA`. What if we're in a situation like I described with ES6 modules where you have a file you want to run but it has nothing to do with `jsA` - it cannot be traced back to being imported by `jsA`. You simply want to execute it before or after `jsA`. Does webpack have the ability to create multiple 'super' files? What's the done thing here?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/ take a look at the entry points, that's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Entry points is definitely what OP is looking for. Here's a question/set of answers for that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907672/how-to-set-multiple-file-entry-and-output-in-project-with-webpack