# How to compile more than one js file

Tags: typescript, webpack

How to compile output to more than one js file (but with different content)?
Currently my project is compiling to one js file based on what I have included index.ts file.
in webpack.common.js I have defined output.filename to the main output file

```
output: {
    ...
    filename : <filename.js>
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to output multible files with different content based on another index.ts? (don't know if multible index.ts is possible but hopefully you understand what I mean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple file entry and output in project with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907672/how-to-set-multiple-file-entry-and-output-in-project-with-webpack)

Comment: [Webpack: Entry Points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/), and [Webpack: Output](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#multiple-entry-points)